# How to use random arguments with the help of flags in Golang

Tags: go, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I want the input from the console to be of anonymous parameters.
My current way of execution is

> ./app -infc=eth0 -ip=192.168.0.1

I don't want this as I need this app to be universal so that I can use it for other purposes as well.

**I want the CLI to be like this**

> ./app -firstparam={{infc},eth0} -secondparam={{ip},192.168.0.1}

So this should basically work by reading the two columns in the parameters.

So it should parse the parameters as a an internal key value pair

Need help on how to store each of the parameter as a key value pair and later use them individually

Comment: OK. What's your question? You've shown an implementation for what you don't want, can you show what you've tried to achieve what you *do* want?

Comment: Let us say every parameter has two columns. So the first column must be assigned as a flag and then second column value must be stored in that flag.

Comment: What I am talking is respect to the Command line

 `./ipchange -firstparam={{firstflag},value} -secondparam={{secondflag},value}`

**All these flags should be declared in the runtime itself and then the value should be assigned**

Comment: The purpose to use _falg_ package is to document flags and access values properly. As is not your case, you should just access _os.Args_ array, and do what you need

Comment: As I told I am making this a universal app. I need the value of the flag documented so that I do not need to come and make changes in the code again.

Comment: You need to do what @MarioSantini suggests and write your own version of the code that accesses os.Args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a barebones example to give you an idea how to process os.Args

```
$ go run main.go --foo asdf --bar xxx --baz ccc
map[--foo:asdf --bar:xxx --baz:ccc]
jsandrew-Mac:osarg jsandrew$ cat main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func manyRandomArg() map[string]string {
    rv := make(map[string]string)
    for ix, x := range os.Args {
        if x[:2] == "--" {
            rv[x] = os.Args[ix+1]
        }
    }
    return rv
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", manyRandomArg())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it thanks to @Vorsprung

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

var key0, key1, key2, key3, key4, filename string
var fileext = regexp.MustCompile(`([a-z]+)\.yaml`)

func manyRandomArg() map[string]string {
    rv := make(map[string]string)
    for ix, x := range os.Args {
        if x[:2] == "--" {
            rv[x] = os.Args[ix+1]
        }
    }
    return rv
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("\n%v\n", manyRandomArg())
    readargs()
}
func readargs() {

    rv := manyRandomArg()
    keys := make([]string, 0, len(rv))
    for key, _ := range rv {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    // Convert map to slice of values.
    values := []string{}
    for _, value := range rv {
        values = append(values, value)
    }

    for keys, values := range rv {
        fmt.Printf("key[%s] value[%s]\n", keys, values)
    }
    if fileext.MatchString(values[0]) {
        fmt.Printf("Value %s\n", values[0])
        filename = values[0]
    } else if fileext.MatchString(values[1]) {
        fmt.Printf("Value %s\n", values[1])
        filename = values[1]
    } else if fileext.MatchString(values[2]) {
        fmt.Printf("Value %s\n", values[2])
        filename = values[2]
    } else if fileext.MatchString(values[3]) {
        fmt.Printf("Value %s\n", values[3])
        filename = values[3]
    } else if fileext.MatchString(values[4]) {
        fmt.Printf("Value %s\n", values[4])
        filename = values[4]
    } else {
        log.Fatal("index 4 fail")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename) // just pass the file name
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    str := string(b) // convert content to a 'string'
    key0 = trimLeftChars(keys[0], 2)
    key1 = trimLeftChars(keys[1], 2)
    key2 = trimLeftChars(keys[2], 2)
    key3 = trimLeftChars(keys[3], 2)
    key4 = trimLeftChars(keys[4], 2)

    // Create replacer with pairs as arguments.
    r := strings.NewReplacer(key0, values[0], key1, values[1], key2, values[2], key3, values[3], key4, values[4])

    // Replace all pairs.
    result := r.Replace(str)
    fmt.Println(result)

    newContents := []byte(result)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("new3.yaml", newContents, 0664)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
func trimLeftChars(s string, n int) string {
    m := 0
    for i := range s {
        if m >= n {
            return s[i:]
        }
        m++
    }
    return s[:0]
}
```